# Can a point be both concave up and concave down

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, derivatives

Example: $f(x) = 3x + (x+2)^{\frac{3}{5}}$

This equation has its inflection point at $x=-2$ and below this point it is concave up, and above this point it is concave down.

My question: Is the point $(-2,-6)$ considered to be concave up, concave down, both, or neither?

My book suggests that it's both but I'm not sure.

Comment: What is your definition of concave up and concave down?

Comment: Second derivative > 0 means concave up etc.

Comment: Alright. By the way I missed the fact that you asked for $x=-2$ and not $f(x)=-2$. Are you sure this is what you meant?

Comment: I meant the point (-2,-6). Edited now

Comment: Try to compute the first and second derivative. You should find that they're undefined at that point.

Comment: Fair. But that was just a random example tbf - what about my original question?

Comment: "Undefined" second derivative means it's neither $>0$ nor $<0$, so it should be neither concave up nor concave down.

Comment: Imagine a situation where the second derivative is defined when it equals zero? i.e. take my example and pretend it's defined!

Comment: @photon If second order derivative is defined then it doesn’t matter if it’s limit exists at that point or not. The definition of infliction points doesn’t require limit to exist.

Comment: @PrabhasKumar yo but my question was is an inflection point concave up, concave down, both or neither?

Comment: An [inflection point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point) is a point where the concavity changes from concave upward to concave downward or vice versa.   A function is [concave upward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) on an interval $I$ if a secant line drawn between any two points in $I$ lies above above the curve.  A function is [concave downward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function) on an interval $I$ if a secant line drawn between any two points in $I$ lies below the curve.

Comment: Since concavity is defined for intervals rather than individual points, your question does not really make sense.

Comment: i.e. if 0 was a real inflection point, would I say it's concave up from (-infinity, 0), or (-infinity, 0]. i.e. does the interval include the inflection point?

Comment: Yes, those intervals include the inflection point, but it does not change the fact that concavity is defined on intervals, not at points. By your definition as you gave in your first comment, inflection points are neither concave up or down, as $f'' = 0$ there, so it is neither $>0$ nor $< 0$. So by your definition, the answer is "no". By N. F. Taussig's definition, the answer is "no point alone is concave up or down". What more do you want?